# Localbitcoins history btc_in_usd rate?

Tags: trading, exchange-rate, price-discovery, localbitcoins

In 2016 Localbitcoins (LBC) [introduced](https://localbitcoins.com/blog/introducing-new-default-pricing-equation/) a new stable variable for price equations called **btc_in_usd**. It was/is based on the rates of the seven most famous exchanges, and LBC calculates a median price from all these sources for **btc_in_usd**.

Is it possible to fetch history **btc_in_usd** for my trade, i.e. the rate which was active on LBC at the moment buyer bidded my advertisement? Or just at any point of time.

Thinking from the other side, can I get the price equation for any trade I made, to calculate history rate myself using traded amount?

If it is not possible, maybe I can get history rates from all these exchanges for and calculate this median myself? Are there sources for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get your price equation via their API:

https://localbitcoins.com/api-docs/#ads

As well as the price at which each of the trades are locked in at:

https://localbitcoins.com/api-docs/#dashboard

It should be possible to write a script to scrape this data and calculate the `btc_in_usd` value using this.

(I'm sure this information is available somewhere in their user panel too, although you might have to look around)